# How to print python openstack object as json

Tags: python, json, openstack, keystone

I'm trying to print a python object as json using json.dumps()

The object is a tenant object from keystoneclient.v2_0.client module.

If I print the object directly I get:

```
<Tenant {u'description': u'', u'enabled': True, u'id': u'dea3061f17df49a1a22f105d5e9bc971', u'name': u'Tets Lab 01'}>
```

Passing it to json.dumps fails i.e

```
my_tenant = keystone.tenants.get('dea3061f17df49a1a22f105d5e9bc971')
json.dumps(my_tenant)
```

The error indicates that it is not serializable
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Other than parsing the string returned from the object, does anyone know if a way I can easily convert this to JSON output?

Comment: python-openstackclient :  https://github.com/openstack/python-openstackclient/blob/master/README.rst  
has a json output option and ties into the python clients.  might be worth using.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up going through the code at:
https://github.com/openstack/python-keystoneclient

The Tenant class extends a base resource, which implements a to_dict() method.
This returns the data in a json format.  https://github.com/openstack/python-keystoneclient/blob/master/keystoneclient/openstack/common/apiclient/base.py

```
my_tenant = keystone.tenants.get('dea3061f17df49a1a22f105d5e9bc971')
json.dumps(my_tenant.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
json.dumps(vars(my_tenant))
```

Comment: Sorry, tried that but same issue: json.dumps(vars(my_tenant)).  I had a look through the tenant code and found the answer see below